# How to synchronise a specific file to a remote FTP server using lftp?

Tags: ftp, lftp

I'm trying to synchronise one file (among other things) using `lftp`.

Even though the docs say that

> --file=FILE                mirror   a   single  file  or  globbed  group  (e.g.
>                                                   /path/to/*.txt)

`lftp` still seems to synchronise all the files of the directory of the passed file.

I'm running this command:

```
lftp -c "set cmd:fail-exit true; set ftp:ssl-allow no; open gocamping;
mirror --reverse --no-perms --exclude=CVS/ --exclude=.cvsignore --delete --verbose=1 --file='/vol/Grozs/Manas vietnes/gocamping/vietne_050011/www/discounts/aaa.php' --target-directory=~/web/discounts;"
```

In directory `/vol/Grozs/Manas vietnes/gocamping/vietne_050011/www/discounts/` there are also files `ooo.php` and `uuu.php`, and all three of them get transferred.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-i` instead.  The excludes are not needed.

`mirror --reverse --no-perms --delete --verbose=1 -i aaa.php   /vol/Grozs/Manasvietnes/gocamping/vietne_050011/www ~/web/discounts`

Comment: Oh, yes, it seems that exactly the "exclude" parameters were the culprits (I had them set globally in a script, because they are needed for other items). If I just remove "excludes", then the resulting command works. Not sure what's the difference between "include" and "file" (or "directory") though.